# spring Should I use @DirtiesContext on every class

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test

I have several junit tests,

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:../business/src/test/resources/application-context-test.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/confA.xml", "classpath:/mvc-dispatcher-servlet-test.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ProductContentControllerTest {
...
}
```

Inside a class all tests have to run in the same context (which is the case).

But I want all my tests classes to be independent.
I was assuming that it was the default behavior, but when I run all the test together, it seems to run too fast.

How does it work? Is the application context started only once for every test class ?

Should I add :

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode= ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
```

on each test class ?

thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Spring caches the application context by default when running tests. The key that Spring uses for the cache is made of the following:

- locations (from @ContextConfiguration)
- classes (from @ContextConfiguration)
- contextInitializerClasses (from @ContextConfiguration)
- contextLoader (from @ContextConfiguration)
- activeProfiles (from @ActiveProfiles)
- resourceBasePath (from @WebAppConfiguration)

All the details of the caching can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching).

In my experience, there is rarely a need to use `@DirtiesContext` in order to force Spring to recreate the context. I haven't come across too many situations where it's needed - the only one that comes to mind easily is the use of a shared cache manager.

You are better using it only on tests that you absolutely positively need it. Execution speed will be far too slow if you use `@DirtiesContext` on every test and you won't be getting anything in return.

Comment: I have a reverse problem, I am not using Dirties anything, but my spring context gets created for each test, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni I can't really say without more info

Comment: The pattern we have is , we have a base class with @RunWith(SpringRunner) and @SpringBootTest etc, and all my tests extend this, so that it uses exact same config, but looks like this polymorphism - spring tests dont like it to cache the context?

Comment: Is it used to clear spring context cache while executing tests? Pls confirm.

Comment: What do you mean by Spring Context Cache?