# Reset database after each test on Spring without using DirtiesContext

Tags: database, spring, integration-testing

I would like to know if there is some way to reset the database after each integration test **without** @DirtiesContext:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

[This works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25361137/2387977) but it is **very** slow, because the Spring context is reloaded each test.

My tests are using **MockMvc**, doing rest calls for an API. Like:

```
mockMvc.perform(put("/products/)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .content(jsonPost))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
```

So, without manual intervention (create and maintain a script to drop and create the tables), the Spring framework offer some alternative?

Answer (score 4):

You can clean the tables you need by doing the following:

1. Inject a JdbcTemplate instance

```java
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

2. Use the class JdbcTestUtils to delete the records from the tables you need to.

```java
JdbcTestUtils.deleteFromTables(jdbcTemplate, "table1", "table2", "table3");
```

3. Call this line in the method annotated with `@After` or `@AfterEach` in your test class:

```java
@AfterEach
void tearDown() throws DatabaseException {
    JdbcTestUtils.deleteFromTables(jdbcTemplate, "table1", "table2", "table3");
}
```

I found this approach in this blog post:
[Easy Integration Testing With Testcontainers](https://mydeveloperplanet.com/2020/05/05/easy-integration-testing-with-testcontainers/)

Comment: the question asks about `being without manual intervention`

Answer (score 3):

In simple case annotate each your test class as `@Transactional` and transaction manager will do rollback after each `@Test` method. Get more information [reading this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#commit).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, but I not mention that my test is using MockMVC, doing rest calls. I think this will not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to the party, but I had the same problem. All the unit tests (which could be considered integration tests) in an application I inherited took approximately 35 minutes to complete, using an embedded H2 as database for tests. All test classes where annotated by @DirtiesContext, usually method level.

So, the database was destroyed and recreated for each method. This takes time.
By removing the dirties annotation and using a database truncation class in the @Before method I now run the complete test suite in about 4 minutes.
If you have anything else than JPA stuff (not handled by the Entity manager) in your Spring context that should be removed between tests you have to do it explicitly.

I can share the DB truncation class if you like, but it is simply using the JPA meta model to find the tables to truncate. Truncation seems to be very efficient in H2. Exceptions for entities based on views, not tables, can be configured.

To make truncation easier, turn off refererential integrity before truncation and switch it back on when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use org.springframework.test.context.jdbc `@Sql({"clear-database.sql"})` and then just write a script to clear the db.

So you'd end up with something like this:

```java
@Test
@Sql({"classpath:sql/clear-database.sql", "classpath:sql/set-up-db.sql"}
void doThings(){
  this.mockMvc.perform(etc..);
}
```