# @Transactional annotation in Spring Test

Tags: java, spring-transactions, spring-test

I am reading Spring docs about `Spring test` in: [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing)

And about using @Transactinoal on tests it says:

> If your test is @Transactional, it rolls back the transaction at the end of each test method by default. However, as using this arrangement with either RANDOM_PORT or DEFINED_PORT implicitly provides a real servlet environment, the HTTP client and server run in separate threads and, thus, in separate transactions. Any transaction initiated on the server does not roll back in this case.

I do not understand what does it exactly means by **Any transaction initiated on the server does not roll back in this case.**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A transaction only works locally. If you are running an integration test you are actually issuing an HTTP request an HTTP request isn't transactional.

Comment: You could simply not use `WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT` nor `WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT`, or use [dirties contexts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html).

Comment: @Vincent C. Thanks for your response. I appreciate if you update your answer with this comment. Using `DirtiesContext` causes the ApplicationContext to be loaded again for the next tests which is timeConsuming. In this case using `WebEnvironment.NONE/MOCK` seems to be better option as you mentioned. Do we miss anything by using NONE or MOCK. I know the application wont run in a container, but does it really hurt?

Comment: I thought you were in need of using one of those two options. If you don't, you most likely just need `WebEnvironment.MOCK` (which is default anyway, so you could simply use the `@SpringBootTest` without any parameters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that your server won't rollback your changes because it will run in another environment than the test environment.
Only changes you have made in your test environment would be rollbacked.

For instance:

```java
@Autowired
private AnyRepository anyRepository;

@Test
@Transactional
void testSave(){
  anyRepository.save(new AnyEntity());
  // Will create an entity from your test environment
}

@Test
@Transactional
void testRead(){
  anyRepository.findAll();
  // Won't find any entities since they were rollbacked
}
```

On the contrary, if you launched a local instance of Spring using `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)` for instance), it is detached from your unit test environment, hence:

```java
@Autowired
MockMvc mvc;

@Test
@Transactional
void testSave(){
  mvc.perform(post(/* enough to create an entity */);
  // Your server, detached from test environment, persists the entity
}

@Test
@Transactional
void testRead(){
  mvc.perform(get(/* enough to get that entity */);
  // Will get previously created entity (if testSave was run before)
}
```

If you want to rollback after sending a web request, you could use the [`@DirtiesContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) annotation to reset your context, or check [Reset database after each test on Spring without using DirtiesContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714118/reset-database-after-each-test-on-spring-without-using-dirtiescontext).

> edit: following comments on original post, it was not clear whether you *needed* to use `WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` or if it was a simple question.
> Most likely, if you do not *need* `WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT`, you can simply use `WebEnvironment.MOCK`, which runs in the same environment that the JUnit tests, hence would actually rollback.

Comment: Thank you Vincent. That actually helped me. Since I am testing integration, allegedly it is better not to use MOCK as it does not run the application in a container so a complete end-to-end test will not happen. But I do not understand what will I miss if I use MOCK instead of (for instance) RANDOM_PORT. In other words, what type of errors could be caught while using RANDOM_PORT that is not possible to be caught when MOCK is used.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58366063/4536931) helps you anyhow?

Comment: No it still does not answer which scenarios is only covered by `RANDOM_PORT` but not with `MOCK`. anyway I will probably ask it in another question.